# Query builder syntax

Tags: qgis, attribute-table

I want to exclude cells with 3 specific values, what's the proper syntax?

I've got `"Attribute" != 'Value1'`, which works fine.  But what's the right syntax to add the other values?  I thought I could just use `OR` followed by the next value, but that doesn't work, e.g. `"Attribute" != 'Value1' OR 'Value2'` but that isn't working.

Comment: Ahh... I realized the problem.  The syntax must be `"Attribute" != 'Value1' AND "Attribute" != 'Value2'`, I can't just stack OR statements.

Comment: Most SQL logical operators are ternary, in the form `val1 op val2`. The only one I can think of which isn't is `val1 BETWEEN val2 AND val3`. Those expressions are combined with `AND` or `OR`. Parenthesis are optional in default evaluation, but are recommended for clarity in all compound queries. And the there's `NOT`, which can flip the evaluation of following expressions, and is used as a modifier in the `val IN (list1,...)` operator as `val NOT IN (list1,...)`. All of this is generic to the SQL language (and common in most languages), and therefore nearly off-topic to GIS SE.

Answer (score 2):

What you've written is interpreted as "Attribute" is not 'Value1' as one condition, and separately to that ... just plain 'Value2' - which makes no sense with the syntax, as it isn't even a condition.

You would need be more explicit, i.e.,`"Attribute" != 'Value1' AND "Attribute" != 'Value2'`

But this can get tedious over many values so I would suggest another approach, `IN` (or in your case, `NOT IN`).

For your example, try `"Attribute" NOT IN ('Value1', 'Value2')`.

Comment: Thanks!  Could you explain the theory behind the `NOT IN` condition, briefly?  Is this saying something like "return all the items with this attribute that do not have this value in it"?  Just trying to parse the meaning a little better in my head so I can remember it.

Comment: Yes, that would be it - it's saying "return all the items where the attribute value is NOT IN this list of values".